# How to best prepare the mind for a problem identification brainstorm?

Tags: problem-solving, brain-training, ideation

I am a manager of a team of software engineers. We often use brainstorming sessions to generate solutions to problems. We use typical cognitive games, e.g. word association, to "warm-up" and facilitate the ideations sessions. These sessions are fruitful.

Tomorrow we are having a brainstorming session to identify problems, not solutions. It would seem that we should prepare our minds with a different technique. Personally, I find that I am best at noticing problems when I am in a negative mindset. Does that hold true against existing research? If so, what would be a good way of getting in to that type of mindset? I would assume causing some kind of mental anguish would facilitate negative thinking. However I don't want to upset my team or do any lasting damage.

Some random ideas that have come to mind include:
- Taking a minute to talk about historical atrocities
- Having food at the session, but not letting anyone eat

If I go down this road, what would be a good decompression method to get people back in to a positive mindset at the end?

Comment: In the end I opted to do a standard warm up (a word association game). The brainstorm was very productive. Once a few problems were articulated, people naturally got in to a complaining groove.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if your approach to "identify[ing] problems, not solutions," will include so-called *reverse* or *negative* brainstorming, in which participants are directed to consider "what can be done to break something instead of focusing solely on narrow-minded fixes,"<sup>1</sup> to be "highly critical, rather than highly creative."<sup>2</sup> If this is the case, the group could "warm up" by applying this technique to some other area: their own lives, their favourite sports teams, public policy issues, etc.

<sup>1</sup> Stephen C. Harper. [How to Solve Problems with Reverse Brainstorming](http://blog.halogensoftware.com/how-to-solve-problems-with-reverse-brainstorming), posted on his TalentSpace Blog, December 14, 2011.

<sup>2</sup> Harper. [Extraordinary Entrepreneurship: The Professional's Guide to Starting an Exceptional Enterprise (Google eBook)](http://books.google.com/books?id=9Kvv2Yv67jYC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=%22brainstorming+to+identify+problems%22&source=bl&ots=4naZsA5Lqv&sig=joFBXIDTy1nR-8VNeaz5AWVbz24&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DJOqUr6eKYrLkAeT4oHICg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22brainstorming%20to%20identify%20problems%22&f=true), 2005, p.78.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll definitely experiment with reverse brainstorming.

Comment: I messed up the first footnote and have now corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share an observation from a personal experiment, loosely based on creative thinking exercises I've read about "somewhere".

Over a course of 21 days, I was looking for innovative products in the world around me. I took pictures of them using my iPhone, and then did a short writeup about what problem this innovation is trying to solve and why I think it is awesome. **In short, the exercise is two fold: first see solutions applied to problems (like below), then see problems that don't have solutions yet.**

For example - looking at cars in a parking lot, I noticed something like this - a roof rack with a little cloth piece in front of it which reduces drag caused by the roof rack. These things did not exist in the 90s:

[image]

Another example would be a promotional flag like the one below. The curved top shape means that the flag is always stiff. It's rotating flag base prevents the flag from tangling around the pole:
[image]

Yet another example would be stackable office chairs like the ones below. Not only does their architecture save storage space, but it allows a single person to move multiple chairs at once:

[image]